# Exotic Operators - why are they useful?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

It would be nice, instead of gathering scattered information on Google (who doesn't understand symbols), to ask the many programming professionals on this site.

I am wondering about a few operators:

1. `x->y` vs `(*x).y`
2. `x.*y` vs `*(x.y)`
3. `x->*y` vs `*(x).*y` vs `*(*(x).y)` vs `*(x->y)`

Compared to each other, is one or the other faster?

Comment: *Why would someone decide to put this in C++?* [Bjarne](http://stackoverflow.com/users/109934/bjarne-stroustrup), we need you here.

Comment: There is absolutely no difference when `operator->` is not overloaded, as `x->y` is merely syntactic sugar for `(*x).y`, and there is no performance difference. I believe they were put in C++ for compatibility with C, which introduced those operators. A notable difference is that in C++ `operator->` can be overloaded while `.` can't.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae Put that comment into an answer? :P

Comment: You should ask one *clear* question at a time.

Comment: Just one question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number 1 is just for convenience and already existed in C. Consider:

```
x->y->z
```

vs

```
(*(*x).y).z
```

The other two operators don't do what you think they do.

```
x.*y
```

calls the member function pointed to by `y` on the object referenced by `x` while

```
x->*y
```

does the same thing but for `x` being a pointer instead.

Here is an example of calling a member function through a pointer:

```
struct Foo {
    void bar();
};

int main() {
    typedef void (Foo::*foo_mem_ptr)();
    // y points to Foo::bar
    foo_mem_ptr y = &Foo::bar;
    Foo x;
    // call y with x as this
    x.*y();
    // same for pointer to x
    Foo *px = &x;
    px->*y();
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be a member _function_ then? How does `y` point to a member function on `x`? If so, couldn't `y` just point to the function on its own?

Comment: @Tqn: I added an example. And, yes, it has to be a function.

Answer (score 2):

1. As far as I know there is absolutely no difference between those operators in basic implementation - they are equivalent. However, You can **override** both `*` and `->` to have different behaviour.
2. They are equivalent, it's just the syntactic sugar.
3. It's 1st and 2nd case mixed together.